# g++ switch to not include own symbolic function names (and debugging data) -?

Tags: c++, unix

Haven't found one, but is there a switch to exclude any debugging data as well as clear-text references to local (own) functions in generated code?

Simple example:

```
void setenv( char* in_str ) {
}
```

...gives me a readable "setenv" name in the executable, which is really not needed, unless it's an interpretive language.

Also in the executable - text names of variables, which is even stranger.

==========

EDIT:

So far tried Solaris strip, GNU strip, g++ -O0 and -s switches. The only way to remove the symbols in question was "strip --strip-all" from the object file (but not the executable), but then it won't link.

So it looks like Richard C is right, and this is indeed needed for lib* runtimes.

Comment: Or it's late binding to a runtime shared library.

Comment: In my case only the std namespace is used, symbolic names in the code are own local functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the gnu `strip` command line tool, or link with the gcc `-s` flag. Note though, the only benefit will be decreased file size. This part of the binary is only loaded into memory if you run the app in a debugger or you generate a stack trace. I prefer to use the strip command, because you can save the debug info separately and load if it you want to get a stack trace for some reason.

examples:

```
g++ -o myexecutable ...
strip --strip-unneeded myexecutable
```

or

```
g++ -s -o myexecutable a.o b.o c.o ...
```